# Draw a Line with texture or sprite

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

In my app i required a line with some texture in it. I draw a simple line with..

ccDrawLine( ccp(0, 0), ccp(s.width, s.height) );

But I required to add texture in it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4404/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial-part-2-textures) by Ray Wenderlich which teaches how to add textures using opengl.